# CSS make buttons justify <li>

Tags: html, css

http://aplicatii-iphone.ro/new-design-iphone/

How do I make all `li` buttons to be justify aligned from left to right?

I mean to not have that small space to right.

IMAGE EXAMPLE HERE

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/asdasn.png/]

Comment: if only you could be more specific

Comment: could you please print your `html` and `css`

Comment: http://aplicatii-iphone.ro/new-design-iphone/css/iphone-buttons.css

Comment: i just want that button to be like a JUSTIFY TEXT

Answer (score 0):

Re-adjust left padding of `#nav a` css selector. Try to put 11px like right padding.

Comment: hmm, still dosen't work, nothing happened, you mean to add to for example "Contact us" button, right?

Comment: I've tried with Inspect Elements, it works. I changed padding of `#nav a {` to `5px 11px`. But yes, it will delete icon space. Your text will be centered though. Increase right padding if you want to make it left aligned.

Comment: i tried that too, but it is not an dyamic solution, i mean it is not perfect, it is still a small 1px 2px space

Comment: I don't get what you want. You can override that value on your CSS file, and adjust the value as you want. The '1px 2px' can easily be removed.

Comment: i have changed for example from 5px 11px 5px 30px to 5px 12px 5px 30px but if i do 1 more pixel the buttons will be on 2 rows ... and i really need to have perfect buttons

Answer (score 0):

set `display:inline-block` for buttons and `text-align: center` for buttons container